# Why won't my UITableView recognize a Touch inside my UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

My UITableViewController has the class name of SettingsViewController.  It contains a property linked to a UITableViewCell called signOutCell.

Why does this not recognize if a user has touched the signOutCell? It is inside SettingsViewController.m?

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if ([touches containsObject:signOutCell])
    {        
        [self triggerActionSheetConfirmation];
    }
}
```

I placed

```
NSLog(@"Received touch");
```

before the if statement, but it never got called. Is touchesBegan:withEvent: never getting called when anything is touched in this TableViewController?

How can I get a simple tap in a UITableViewCell to call the method triggerActionSheetConfirmation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `UITableViewDelegate` method `tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:`. In that method get the cell of the row clicked via the `UITableView` method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Then use an `if` statement to compare the cell with the `UITableView` outlet property you created. Then run your method if it evaluates to that outlet.

Comment: Thank you.  This worked specifically to fit my concern because I had multiple sections.  This is what I used. - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([[tableView indexPathForCell:signOutCell] isEqual:indexPath])
    {
        [self triggerActionSheetConfirmation];
    }
}

Answer (score 2):

Add a gesture recogniser to the UITableViewCell and set the target as your SettingsViewController.