# How to get custom cell data when row is tapped?

Tags: ios, xcode4, storyboard

I have a custom table view cell with 3 fields in it.  I need to get the data in one of those fields to use in a SQLite query.

I've looked at cellForRowAtIndexPath, but don't see how to address the particular cell I want (it was defined with an IBOutlet, so it has a name) and get it's value.

Comment: Check out this thread: "Why won't my UITableView recognize a Touch inside my UITableViewCell?"

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813417/why-wont-my-uitableview-recognize-a-touch-inside-my-uitableviewcell/9813619#9813619

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out... here is the code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {

    SingletonClass *shareInstance= [SingletonClass sharedInstance];
    sArray *sa = [shareInstance.listOfSites objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  //  (rows are zero based)
    NSString *labelContent = sa.sSiteID;  //  labelContent = site_id

    //  get list of sites based on selected row
    slSQLite *dbCode = [[slSQLite alloc] init];
    [dbCode getListOfSites:labelContent];  //  labelContent is used to build query
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When the row is tapped, your didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method will be called.  In that method, you can use [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] to get the row's cell.  Then you can get whatever you need out of the cell.

Comment: I already figured that part out... what I need to know is HOW to get the contents of "cellxyz".